# Connection timed out when I try to deploy my node with PM2 to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, pm2

I try to follow [this tutorial](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/) ..

I have created and added the keys in heroku using `heroku keys:add`

```
ssh -vT git@heroku.com

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: C:/Users/rider/.ssh/heroku
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to heroku.com ([50.19.85.156]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
shell request failed on channel 0
```

### The problem

When I execute the command `pm2 deploy ecosystem.json production setup` result ..

```
λ pm2 deploy ecosystem.json production setup
--> Deploying to production environment
--> on host serve-provaninja.herokuapp.com
ssh: connect to host <myhost>.herokuapp.com port 22: Connection timed out

  setup paths failed

Deploy failed
```

### My project files

**Procfile**

```
web: node main.js && pm2 logs all
```

**ecosystem.json**

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"       : "Project name",
    "script"      : "index.js"
  }],

  "deploy" : {
      "production" : {
        "user" : "git",
        "host" : "<myhost>.herokuapp.com",
        "ref"  : "origin/master",
        "repo" : "git@github.com:<myproject>.git",
        "path" : "/var/www/production",
        "post-deploy" : "npm install --production && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json —env production"
      }
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');
var os = require("os");

var MACHINE_NAME = os.hostname();
var PRIVATE_KEY  = process.env.KEYMETRICS_PRIVATE_KEY;
var PUBLIC_KEY   = process.env.KEYMETRICS_PUBLIC_KEY;

var ecosystem = require('./ecosystem.json');
var maxMemory = process.env.WEB_MEMORY || 512;

pm2.connect(function() {
  ecosystem.apps.forEach(function(app) {
      pm2.start({
        script    : app.script,
        name      : app.name,
        max_memory_restart : maxMemory + 'M',
        post_update: ["npm install"]
      }, errback);
  });
});

function errback(err,proc) {
  pm2.interact(PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY, MACHINE_NAME, function() {
   pm2.launchBus(function(err, bus) {
     console.log('[PM2] Log streaming started');
     bus.on('log:out', function(packet) {
       console.log('[App:%s] %s', packet.process.name, packet.data);
     });

     bus.on('log:err', function(packet) {
       console.error('[App:%s][Err] %s', packet.process.name, packet.data);
     });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have my pm2 processes started in heroku using boot scripts, similar to what you have already.

this is the tutorial i followed to achieve this:
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers/

edit: to add some detail, i do not believe there is a way to easily ssh into a heroku dyno. because the dyno formation is a dynamically generated architecture, and theres no static machine or ip to tap into, ssh is not usable the way you want out of the box

Comment: this tutorial is how to run your app in the cloud, my problem is how to deploy using `pm2 deploy ecosystem.json production setup`

Comment: how do you deploy your app to heroku?

Comment: i use travis ci to deploy to heroku:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku